# Java student in need of assistance on a prompt, been working on this for a week, need some advice

Tags: java

Currently I have three classes and this is our prompt:

Implement methods in the provided Course class. I have provided a class called Student. A student is described by a first name, last name, and ID. Review this class and make sure you understand the code. Then implement the three missing methods in the Course class, as described below. A course is described by a name and a course roster. The roster is stored as an array of Student objects.

-Add code to the constructor to initialize the roster.

-Add any instance data variables you need to make the program function. Think about what variables you might need. For any variables you include, add getters and setters for those variables (as appropriate) and initialize the variables in the constructor.

-Write a method to add a student to the course roster. The method should return true if the student is added successfully (meaning there is room for the student) and false otherwise.

-Write a method to drop a student from the course roster. The method should return true if the student was successfully dropped (meaning they were in the course and no longer are) and false otherwise.

-Implement the toString method. This method should return text that contains the course name, the number of students enrolled, the maximum number of student that can be enrolled, and a printed roster of enrolled students (if there are any).
I have provided a driver program you can use to test your code and sample output. You might add additional code to the driver to test your Course class.

I apologize for the lack of convention, I'm still a beginner at java, please me patient with me.

Edit: Sorry I wasn't specific enough, my problem is the boolean dropstudent method, I'm not sure how to implement it and add in codes to drop students from the array I added students into. I tried but it's not working out.

```
public class Course {
    private String name;

    private Student[] roster;
    private int maxStudents;
    private static int numberOfStudents = 0;

    public Course(String name, int maxStudents) {
        setName(name);
        setMaxStudents(maxStudents);
        // ADD CODE HERE (IF NECESSARY)
        roster = new Student[maxStudents];
    }

    public int getMaxStudent() {
        return maxStudents;
    }

    public void setMaxStudents(int maxStudents) {
        if(maxStudents > 0) {
            this.maxStudents = maxStudents;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public void setNumberOfStudents(int numberOfStudents) {
        this.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
    }

    public boolean addStudent(Student s) {
        //IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD
        /* int counter2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        if (roster[i] != null)
            counter2++;
            }
        if (counter2 != 5) {
        roster[counter++] = s;
        return true;
        }else   
        return false;
        */
        if (numberOfStudents != maxStudents){
        roster[numberOfStudents++] = s;
        return true;
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean dropStudent(Student s) {
        // IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD
        /*int counter2 = 5;
        for(int i = maxStudents; i>0; i--){
        if (roster[i] != null)
            counter2--;
            }
        if (counter2 != 0) */
        if (numberOfStudents != 0){
        roster[numberOfStudents--] = null;
        return true;
        } else {        
        return false;
        }
}
        @Override
    public String toString() {
        // IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD
        return "Roster:" + roster[0] + "\n" + roster[1]+ "\n" + roster[2] + "\n"
        + roster[3]+ "\n" + roster[4]+ "\n";
        }
}

public class Student {
    private String firstName, lastName, id;
    private boolean tuitionPaid;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String id, boolean tuitionPaid) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setID(id);
        setTuitionPaid(tuitionPaid);
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String id) {
        this(firstName, lastName, id, true);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isTuitionPaid() {
        return tuitionPaid;
    }

    public void setTuitionPaid(boolean tuitionPaid) {
        this.tuitionPaid = tuitionPaid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Student) {
            Student otherStudent = (Student) obj;
            return id.equalsIgnoreCase(otherStudent.id);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " (" + id + ")";
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't just copy & paste a homework question and expect a full response. Please focus your question and rephrase the title, we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: what's the issue with above code?

Comment: Use language to explain yourself, don't just throw out specs and code. Read and act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

OK so here's what you currently have:

```
private Student[] roster;
private int maxStudents;
private static int numberOfStudents = 0;
```

I'm inferring that `roster` should contain all students currently in the course, `maxStudents` should contain the limit on the number of enrollees, and `numberOfStudents` is the number of students currently enrolled.

(There's a mistake: `numberOfStudents` should not be `static`!!!)

So what should `dropStudent(s)` do?

1. It should find the position of `s` in `roster`.
2. It should remove `s` from `roster`.
3. It should adjust `numberOfStudents`.

Now there is one more thing that it has to do.  Your `addStudent` assumes that it can add the student at the position given by `numberOfStudents`.  The assumption is that all of the existing students are to the left of the position of `numberOfStudents`.  This assumption is an **invariant** of your class.  You have to make sure that it is still true after you have removed `s` in `removeStudent`.

Your current implementation of `removeStudent` does not maintain the invariant.  It is buggy.

Think about how you can maintain that invariant.  Hint: there is more than one way.  There is an obvious way, and there is a clever way that requires less code.